# Correcting JSON string with incorrect notation?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working on a web application witch javascript, and I have to receive and parse a JSON string that looks like this:

```
{name:"", house:""}
```

What's the best way to convert it to proper notation?

```
{"name":"", "house":""}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you wanna change it? it seems right until you have special characters in the names/

Comment: If you're receiving a string in that format, it's not JSON.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = '{name:"", house:""}';
var newStr = JSON.stringify( eval( '(' + str + ')' ) );
console.log(newStr); //{"name":"", "house":""}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xgnzd/)

Do not use `eval` if the data source is untrusted though.

---

By the way, are you sure you're receiving a badly formed JSON string and it is not just an object? In case you're using jQuery, it automatically parses JSON responses into objects. In that case you'd just call `JSON.stringify` passing the object to make a valid JSON string from it, or access the request's `responseText`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xgnzd/1/) with jQuery Ajax.