# Error with parsing string type to JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to parse my string to a JSON object, but it doesn't work. I get a syntax error when I debug the code. Here is the string I want to parse:

```
var listString = "{ title: 'MySchema'," + "root: {id:'"  + headID + "'," 
+   "title:'" + topHead[0].Designation  + "'," + "subtitle:'" + headName + "',";
liststring = liststring + "{ id: '" + head + "'," + "title: '" + childs[cnt].Designation + "'," + "subtitle: '" + title + "'," + "type: '" +  childs[cnt].Typav + "'";

liststring = getChildNodes(tasksEntries, head, liststring); liststring = liststring + "},";}liststring = liststring + "]}}";} listString = childliststring;
```

$.parseJSON(listString );

I don't get any JSON objects in return. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, that string is not a valid JSON object so it makes sense that you can't parse it as one.

Answer (score 0):

You have many many Syntax errors, one of it is the comma here `'staff'},]}}"` 
Next, every String have to be in " quotes, so every name property and value. ALso Integer values have no quotes.

The correct json would be:

```
{
    "title":"myTitle",
    "root":{
        "id":1,
        "title":"CEO",
        "subtitle":"John Doe",
        "children":[
            {
                "id":2,
                "title":"COO",
                "subtitle":"Steve Berman",
                "type":"staff"
            },
            {
                "id":3,
                "title":"CTO",
                "subtitle":"Mark Claskov",
                "type":"staff"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You can test you json here:
http://json.parser.online.fr/beta/

Answer (score 0):

First you forgot to put `;` at the end of `$.parseJSON(myyVar)`:

```
var myyVar = {title: 'myTitle',root: {id:'1',title:'CEO',subtitle:'John Doe',children: [{ id: '2',title: 'COO',subtitle: 'Steve Berman',type: 'staff'},{ id: '3',title: 'CTO',subtitle: 'Mark Claskov',type: 'staff'},]}};
```

Second your main variable `myyVar` is the one you must use in `$.parseJSON()` and not `myvar`:

```
$.parseJSON(myyVar);
```

And lastly, [`you can correct improper json format`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324456/correcting-json-string-with-incorrect-notation):

```
var myyVar = {title: 'myTitle',root: {id:'1',title:'CEO',subtitle:'John Doe',children: [{ id: '2',title: 'COO',subtitle: 'Steve Berman',type: 'staff'},{ id: '3',title: 'CTO',subtitle: 'Mark Claskov',type: 'staff'},]}};
var newVar = JSON.stringify(myyVar );

alert($.parseJSON(newVar));
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TUK59/1/). [try to change `alert()` to `console.log()` to see what's going on thru browser's console]

Comment: The function takes in a string with the '{"key":"value"}' format. So your answer might still be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is malformed. Read the [parseJSON API](https://api.jquery.com/JQuery.parseJSON/):

> Description: Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting
>   JavaScript object.
>
> version added: 1.4.1jQuery.parseJSON( json ) json Type: String The
>   JSON string to parse.

Your JSON string should be in `'{"key":"value"}'` format. Passing in a malformed JSON string results in a JavaScript exception being  thrown. For example, the following are all malformed JSON strings:

```
{test: 1} //(test does not have double quotes around it).
{'test': 1} //('test' is using single quotes instead of double quotes).
```

The JSON standard does not permit "control characters" such as a tab or newline. 
An example like `$.parseJSON( '{ "testing":"1\t2\n3" }' )` will throw an error in 
most implementations because the JavaScript parser converts the string's tab and 
newline escapes into literal tab and newline; doubling the backslashes like 
`"1\\t2\\n3"` yields expected results. This problem is often seen when injecting 
JSON into a JavaScript file from a server-side language such as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

jour JSON string should be in '{"key":"value"}' format

`JSON.parse("{id:'1'}");`

SyntaxError: Unexpected token i

`JSON.parse("{'id':'1'}");`

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '

`JSON.parse('{"id":"1"}');`

Object {id: "1"}

`JSON.parse('{"id":1}');`

Object {id: 1}

Answer (score 0):

Use this to parse the json string.

```
JSON.parse(json_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your String should be like this.

```
{
"title": "myTitle",
"root": {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "CEO",
    "subtitle": "JohnDoe",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "COO",
            "subtitle": "SteveBerman",
            "type": "staff"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "CTO",
            "subtitle": "MarkClaskov",
            "type": "staff"
        }
      ]
   }
}
```

You can test whether your JSON is valid or not in this link http://jsonlint.com/